# How do I fix an App Service deployment failure for lack of disk space when there is plenty?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, deployment, web-applications

I have a React web app in VS Code and I have the Azure App Service extension installed. I have used this to deploy my app several months ago successfully. But now when I click the up arrow icon  the deployment starts, runs for a few minutes and then fails telling me that there is not enough space on the disk. Looking at the output messages, I see it is using the D: disk which is an external USB drive with 1.69 TB free of 1.81TB. So why this failure?

An earlier version of the web app (acestrader.com)is hosted on Azure now from a prior deployment using the same Azure extension from VS Code. I don't think it used the D: drive since that is not plugged in most of the time.

The Output Messages:

```
5:47:27 PM AcesTrader: Starting deployment...
5:47:32 PM AcesTrader: Creating zip package...
5:53:48 PM AcesTrader: Zip package size: 218 MB
5:53:49 PM AcesTrader: Fetching changes.
5:53:49 PM AcesTrader: Cleaning up temp folders from previous zip deployments and extracting pushed zip file D:\local\Temp\zipdeploy\zrlvv2if.zip (208.16 MB) to D:\local\Temp\zipdeploy\extracted
5:55:28 PM AcesTrader: There is not enough space on the disk.\r
5:55:34 PM AcesTrader: Deployment failed.
```

What do I do to fix this?

Comment: In Azure Portal , You can monitor the disk space under “Quotas” tab at the Web App level. Go to Web App -> Quotas -> you can see the File System Storage.

Comment: In Microsoft.Storage: Quotas/My quotas, I see that my usage is 2% in East US. All others are 0% usage. Maximum capacity is not shown.

Comment: I fell back to my original way to deploy; using WinSCP to upload the files via FTP. Worked like a charm.